# How can I automatically advance to the next member of a filtered group upon webform submission?

Tags: webform-civicrm

I've created a webform for a phone caller to use when calling members of a Civi Group who have already signed a card, to sign the Group members up for follow up activities.

Once the phone caller completes the call, and submits the form, I want a new form to populate with the name of the next Group member to be called.

The "target" contact is an Existing Contact, I have the Form Widget set to Static, under Default Value I have Set default contact from Auto - From Filters, and under Filters I've chosen only the relevant Group.

But the first name in the Group reappears upon Submit.

Comment: Something to consider when doing this - if you have multiple callers, you want to avoid having two of them both grab the same "next call" off the top of the stack. When we did something similar, we had the callers assign calls to a stack which they "owned", and then call off their own stack; this prevents duplicate calls going out. This is even more likely if the call is not moved off the stack until call completes.

Comment: Chris, good point, right now just trying to make it work for one caller at a time. With multiple callers I can create Groups for each callers assigned contacts - though then the challenge is enabling a filter for each caller to choose their Group.

Answer (score 3):

This is no quick solution (though I suspect there isn't a reliable one), but just as a note for future development--this situation of grabbing the "next call" is precisely why reserving contacts in the phonebank feature exists.  I think the real solution (that may be out of your immediate budget and timeframe Joe, but is what would actually tackle the issue) is to have a nice frontend on the phonebank.

Just as I call exposing a profile in create mode for semi-privileged users "intern mode"--for allowing someone to enter contacts without actually giving them full CiviCRM access--a phonebank listing would let someone go down the list of contacts reserved for them and potentially reserve a few more as the caller gets to the end of the list.  That would solve this problem in a non-Drupal-centric way, use the nice "reserve" feature to handle the situation in Chris's comment, and provide a complete experience for those running and staffing the phone bank.